# LDAP authentication failing

Tags: node.js, authentication, active-directory, ldap, ntlm

I have a nodejs application that successfully authenticates using LDAP locally using passport-ldapauth.

However, in another environment it is not working. I have written a .net app that can successfully query LDAP. The different is that it uses NTLM.

I am not familiar with NTLM and how this affects my nodejs project.

```
LDAP_URL = ldap://<ldap_server_ip address>
LDAP_BIND_DN = ldapadmin
LDAP_BIND_CREDENTIALS = password123
LDAP_SEARCH_BASE = DC=mydomain,DC=com
LDAP_SEARCH_FILTER = (sAMAccountName={{username}})
```

Am I talking apples and oranges here? I get invalid credentials even though they work in my .net app.

nodesjs code:

```
super(
  (
    request: Request,
    callback
  ) => {
    const options = {
      server: {
        url: getEnvValue('LDAP_URL'),
        bindDN: getEnvValue('LDAP_BIND_DN'),
        bindCredentials: getEnvValue('LDAP_BIND_CREDENTIALS'),
        searchBase: getEnvValue('LDAP_SEARCH_BASE'),
        searchFilter: getEnvValue('LDAP_SEARCH_FILTER'),
      },
      passReqToCallback: true,
    };
    callback(null, options);
  }
);
```

Any thoughts would greatly appreciated.

Gina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many many hours, the answer was simpler than expected:

```
LDAP_BIND_DN = mydomain\ldapadmin
```

Gina